# How to know the Bluetooth MAC address in Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, bluetooth, alpine-linux

I am deploying a docker in Raspberry Pi 3. Inside docker I need to know the MAC of Bluetooth device. Normally I would find that using

> hciconfig | grep "BD Address" | awk '{ print $3}'

`hciconfig` is not installed by default inside Alpine Linux. I think it comes under `bluez` package so I installed by adding following line in my `Dockerfile`:

> RUN apk add --no-cache bluez

But even after that I'm unable to run `hciconfig`. It says

> sh: hciconfig: not found

So, what's the way to install `hciconfig` in Alpine? Also, if there's another easier way to get the Bluetooth MAC, that would also work.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpine package [`bluez`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=bluez&branch=edge) does not include `hciconfig` any more. It has been deprecated and is available in [`bluez-deprecated`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=bluez-deprecated&branch=edge).

Further, one can get BD address from latest `bluez` using the command:

> bluetoothctl list

Comment: Same is possible via `bluetoothctl info`